# What is the largest possible length of a prime number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number ,

set $f(p)=2p+1$ and define $f^n(p)=f\circ f\circ\cdots\circ f(p)$ composition by $f,$ $n$ times.

And define length of $p$, $L(p)$ as maximum of $n$ such that $f^i(p)$ is prime for all $0\leq i< n$.

For example, $L(3)=2$ since we have chain $3-7$  and $L(2)=5$ as $2-5-11-23-47$.

My question what is the largest possible  length for all prime ?

i.e if $M=\sup \{L(p):p\  \text{is prime number} \}$, what is $M$?

Comment: That max should be a sup, as it could be infinite. You might want to try using the heuristic density of Sophie Germain primes to give a heuristic for the probability that a given prime has length $\geq n$. (Remark that $L(p)\geq 1$ if and only if $p$ is a Sophie Germain prime.) That might tell you whether to expect $M<\infty$ or $M=\infty$.

Comment: Examine [Cunningham Chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_chain) of the first kind.

Comment: @Peter: Spot on! :)

Comment: As far as I can tell that should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bruno points out, there is no way to settle this question with current knowledge.

However, there is a small note: let your first prime be called $p.$ There are many odd primes $q$ **for which $2$ is a primitive root** and for which $$ p \neq -1 \pmod q.  $$
Your function then has
$$  L(p) \leq 2q - 3  $$ for any such $q.$ Furthermore, if $q$ is **not** one of the $f^n(p),$ then
$$  L(p) \leq q - 2.  $$
This applies to the smallest possible $q$ you can find, so there is an upper bound for any given $p.$

For example, $2 \neq -1 \pmod 5,$ so $L(2) \leq 7.$

When $q$ has 2 as a primitive root, then your sequence, taken $\pmod q,$ has the fixed point $-1 \pmod q,$ and everything else shows up in a long sequence of $q-1$ distinct values, including $0 \pmod q.$ If the prime $q$ is not part of the sequence, a number congruent to $0 \pmod q$ is composite. If the prime $q$ is part of the sequence, the first occurrence is allowed to be $q$ itself, but any other occurrence is a composite number.

Hmmm. In particular, if 2 is a primitive root $\pmod p$ it self, then $L(p) \leq p-1.$ We get this because $p$ occurs in the very first position.

The primes up to 1000 [for which 2 is a primitive root](https://oeis.org/A001122) are
$$      3,     5,    11,    13,    19,    29,    37,    53,    59,    61,    67,    83,   101,   107,   131,   139,   149,   163,   173,   179,   181,   197,$$
$$   211,   227,   269,   293,   317,   347,   349,   373,   379,   389,   419,   421,   443,   461,   467,   491,   509,   523,$$
$$   541,   547,   557,   563,   587,   613,   619,   653,   659,   661,   677,   701,   709,   757,   773,   787,   797,   821,   827,$$
$$   829,   853,   859,   877,   883,   907,   941,   947,
   $$

Evidently much easier to show a chain is short than to find a long one, as the current world record is length 14. See http://oeis.org/A005602

Comment: Thanks for your extended search.